# Implementing an animated ValidationSummary with ASP.Net and jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

I'm just getting started with jQuery, and one of the things I want to do is build a slicker ValidationSummary for WebForms.

I envision something like StackOverflow's notification system, where when you log in after awhile an area at the top of the screen animates down and maybe lets you know that you've got a new badge. If you click the 'x' it animates away.

That's what I have in mind... Except for validation.

I realize this is tricky because ASP.Net validation has both client and server-side aspects (CustomValidators), and I'm not sure if there are even any hooks to do this in a non-hideous fashion.

However, I do know that there are third party validation suites that are supposed to be interesting.

Any thoughts to get me started? Or is this maybe a solved problem that I can just download somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can start by looking at these: http://jquerylist.com/#form_validation

Answer (score 1):

So far the best I've found is this article: http://www.delphicsage.com/home/blog.aspx/d=273/title=jQuery_Style_ASPNET_Form_Validators__Part_Deux_Let039s_Get_Animated

...I will update with additional findings.